# before delete trigger not updating related records

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, method

So I've added an extra method to my earlier trigger to take into account the case of a deleted opportunity not updating its related custom object amount, which is pretty similar to the before update trigger that works correctly, but I can't find the error in this one (dev console doesn't show any problems and neither did general logs), I compared it line by line to the first method but didn't find the mistake(s). Could anyone with a keen eye please help me see where this is going wrong?

```
public static void DeleteOppAdjustment(Map<Id, Opportunity> triggerOld) {
    List<Opportunity> oppsWStrategies = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Id> strategiesToUpdate = new List<Id>();    
    
    for (Opportunity opp : triggerOld.values()) {
        if (triggeringOpp.Strategy__c != null) {
            oppsWStrategies.add(triggeringOpp);
            strategiesToUpdate.add(triggeringOpp.Strategy__c);
        }
    }
    
    if (!oppsWStrategies.IsEmpty()) {
       Map<Id, Strategy__c> strategyMap = new Map<Id,Strategy__c>([select Id, Opportunities_Open__c, 
      Opportunities_Won__c, Opportunities_Lost__c from Strategy__c where Id IN: strategiesToUpdate.values()]);
       List<Strategy__c> updateStrategies = new List<Strategy__c>();
        
        for (Opportunity deletedOpp : oppsWStrategies) {
            Strategy__c strategyToChange = strategyMap.get(deletedOpp.Strategy__c);
            
            if (!deletedOpp.IsClosed && (strategyToChange.Opportunities_Open__c != null)) {
                strategyToChange.Opportunities_Open__c = strategyToChange.Opportunities_Open__c - deletedOpp.Amount;
                updateStrategies.add(strategyToChange);
            } else if (deletedOpp.IsWon && (strategyToChange.Opportunities_Won__c !=null)) {
                strategyToChange.Opportunities_Won__c = strategyToChange.Opportunities_Won__c - deletedOpp.Amount;
                updateStrategies.add(strategyToChange);
            } else if (!deletedOpp.IsWon && (strategyToChange.Opportunities_Lost__c !=null)) {
                strategyToChange.Opportunities_Lost__c = strategyToChange.Opportunities_Lost__c - deletedOpp.Amount;
                updateStrategies.add(strategyToChange);
            }
        }
        
        if(!updateStrategies.IsEmpty()) {
            update updateStrategies;
        }            
    }        
}
```

Comment: can you share your trigger code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, turns out I had forgotten to rename my first loop variable in there after a different attempt to get the opp's Id. Facepalming myself after all the hours I wasted cursing the code.